# Disable JSF warning for pattern in Eclipse

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

My JSF pages use a resource bundle to resolve labels, so the texts tags look like this:

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{dictionary['label.description']}" />
```

In Eclipse I get a warning under `label.description` saying **"label.description" cannot be resolved**.

The thing is my pages have sometimes hundreds of labels, and the warning panel gets cluttered with the **... cannot be resolved** messages.

I would like to instruct Eclipse to ignore these warnings, maybe using a regex pattern like:`[#{dictionary\[\'].*` or something. That way I can focus on "real" warning messages, like wrong tags and the like.

Comment: I wouldn't modify your repository to remove faulty IDE warnings, I can only imagine it becoming messy (there may be settings you can tinker with). Sorry I can't help, not familiar with JSF.

Comment: Use JBoss Tools plugins. Very suffisticated and proper validation and code complete.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianMitev, I already have JBoss Tools installed in my Eclipse, but I cannot see where in the configuration can I disable a warning using a text pattern.